# Spring kafka with virtual threads and @Async

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, virtual-threads

I've looked in `spring-kafka` docs but it makes no mention of using `@KafkaListener` with `@Async` taking into account virtual threads.

For example, in Spring Boot's config we set:

```
spring.threads.virtual.enabled = true
```

Then we would have a method annotated with @KafkaListener and @Async:

```
  @Async
  @KafkaListener(topics = "some-topic")
  public void consume(ConsumerRecord<String, String> record) {
      //code here
  }
```

Given a simplistic scenario of a single partition and a single consumer and no batching, I've noticed each record consumed is consumed by a different virtual thread.

With we remove `@Async`, it goes to "normal" `@KafkaListener` behaviour, a single thread would consume all records in order.

Now, I'm fully aware that in this case `@Async` would prevent records from being consumed in order, but other than that, are there any pitfalls of doing this? Or any benefits?

I'm just wondering if this would be more scalable, piggybacking on virtual threads to consume each message, than the usual one thread per consumer.

Since there's no mention of virtual threads in spring-kafka's docs, I'm wondering if using `@Async` is this context is a dangerous thing to do in any way.

Anyone out there has experimented with this? Cheers.

Comment: I only would say that I would never do that to break the Kafka consumer behavior. It is really recommended to do the record processing from one partition in the order from a single thread. Just because the acknowledgement in Kafka is made my the offset, not per record. So, you may process the record `10` , but fail on `5` and still all `10` are going to be committed.

Comment: Is this question about using `@Async` on a Consumer or about using virtual threads for a particular `@Async` case? If platform threads will be used, the records anyway will be consumed out of order. As for benefits of using virtual threads for Consumer, it depends on the nature of Consumer's actions. Virtual threads are _lightweight_ and so should be these actions and, preferably, _pin_ as less as possible. BTW, you can use virtual threads for one `@Async` and platform ones - for another.

Comment: Hi @igor.zh! Thanks for your input. I think this is mostly about the benefits of parallel kafka consumer with `v-threads` using @Async and @KafkaListener together. To be able to scale message processing beyond the number of partitions of a topic. 

It's just seems the virtual threads solution is new territory so I was wondering if anyone had tried and found issues. Since it doesn't seem to be mentioned anywhere in spring-kafka's docs.

Comment: Understood. I am not a Kafka man, but I believe, if you are aware of danger of out-of-ordering when `@Async` is used, then v-threads won't bring any _semantic_ difference against platform threads. Benefits of v-threads would depend on the nature of Consumer actions. That's why Kafka, IMHO, doesn't say anything about v-threads. If I were you I'd introduce an Executor for `@Async`. In fact, you could have 3 types of threading with such approach: zero (in-consumer), platform and virtual async threads, so that you could switch between them (possibly, dynamically) and see what suits you best.

Answer (score 0):

Although not directly related to Kafka, a very basic, skeleton, Executor below might allow you to switch between the platform, virtual, and in-thread modes  to see what suits you best:

```
import org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor;
import org.springframework.core.task.TaskExecutor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class ThreadingModeExecutor implements TaskExecutor {

    public enum ThreadingMode {
        SAME_THREAD,
        PLATFORM,
        VIRTUAL
    }

    private volatile ThreadingMode threadingMode = ThreadingMode.SAME_THREAD;
    private final SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor platformExecutor;
    private final SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor virtualExecutor;

    public ThreadingModeExecutor() {
        platformExecutor = new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor();
        virtualExecutor = new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor();
        virtualExecutor.setVirtualThreads(true);
    }

    public ThreadingModeExecutor(ThreadingMode threadingMode) {
        this();
        this.threadingMode = threadingMode;
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(Runnable task) {
        switch (threadingMode) {
        case ThreadingMode.SAME_THREAD:
            task.run();
            break;
        case ThreadingMode.PLATFORM:
            platformExecutor.execute(task);
            break;
        case ThreadingMode.VIRTUAL:
            virtualExecutor.execute(task);
        }
    }

    public ThreadingMode getThreadingMode() {
        return threadingMode;
    }

    public void setThreadingMode(ThreadingMode threadingMode) {
        this.threadingMode = threadingMode;
    }

}
```

A method, annotated with `@Async` will look like this:

```
@Async("threadingModeExecutor")
public void seeCastellan() {
    // ...
}
```

Note that Spring Boot `spring.threads.virtual.enabled` is completely ignored in this case, because the Executor Spring bean is "manually" created. This also means that the design can be used in non-Spring Boot, plain Spring Bean/Context applications, e.g. war-based; `@Async` usage has to be properly configured, of course.

The snippet assumes that the `ThreadingModeExecutor` class is in the scanned path, e.g. by means of `@ComponentScan`. Alternatively, the correspondent Spring bean can be created in `@Configuration` classes. The Spring bean name, however, must coincide with the `value` parameter of `@Async` annotation, `threadingModeExecutor` in the snippet.

Be aware that in this snippet `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor`s do not pool threads, which might be an issue for platform threads.